# In GWT Bootstrap, how to assign different styles to different instances of same Bootstrap elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt

for GWT Bootstrap, I have NavLists definitions as:

```xml
<b:NavList>
    <b:NavHeader>My Header</b:NavHeader>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu1:">My Menu1</b:NavLink>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu2:" active="true">My Menu2</b:NavLink>
</b:NavList>
```

In the same application I have 2 kind of components like this, (1) one is placed on a white panel as left menu, (2) the other is placed on a dargreen panel as a bottom menu. Both are NavLists.

So I have the problem to assign different colours to different instances of the same Bootstrap elements. I suppose can do it straight in UiBinder but, after trying everything I do not find the right settings. The Bootstrap selector that I need to override in the UiBinder is (from less nav files):

```css
.nav-list > li > a {
   padding: 3px 15px;
   color: #FF0000;   <======= how to override this color in UiBinder
}
```

I figure out this would be a very common use case, same element, instances with different style. How can it be addressed?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a custom style name as you would usually do with any style.

```xml
<ui:style>
    .myCustomStyle > li > a {
        color: YOUR COLOR HERE;
    }
</ui:style>

...

<b:NavList styleName="{style.myCustomStyle}">
    <b:NavHeader>My Header</b:NavHeader>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu1:">My Menu1</b:NavLink>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu2:" active="true">My Menu2</b:NavLink>
</b:NavList>
```

The example above has the style directly in the UiBinder file. You could alternatively use [`ClientBundle`](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) to do it. That way you can use the same style on many widgets on in different places in the app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, this is the kind of setting I am looking for. Tried and works BUT, then, is missing the .nav-list class in Bootstrap = renders as a common list (without Bootstrap style). Tried instead addStyleNames="{style.myCustomStyle}" adding also !important to the CSS but, then, nothing happens = gets the Bootstrap style. One dirty hack looks repeating full Bootstrap class, but there are more elements implied in the selector .nav-list > li > a (actually, the responsible for this color is the nested anchor). Doing it in the Java would be ugly fix. Any similar experience? Tkx

Comment: yujuuuu, got the clean fix. Commented above.

Comment: You can try using [ClientBundle](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html).

Answer (score 0):

By combining these ideas, I have got the clean fix. The solution is just using the right selector for the nested anchor element but assigned to parent because anchor is not available in UiBinder, i.e.:

```
<ui:style>
    .myCustomStyle > li > a {               (<---- see this selector)
        color: YOUR COLOR HERE;
    }
</ui:style>

...

<b:NavList addStyleNames="{style.myCustomStyle}">     (<---- see applied to parent and addStyleNames)
    <b:NavHeader>My Header</b:NavHeader>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu1:">My Menu1</b:NavLink>
    <b:NavLink href="#menu2:" active="true">My Menu2</b:NavLink>
</b:NavList>
```